# Git: Why does previous fetch+merge commit disappear after fetch+rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-remote

**TL;DR:** If I fetch remote changes into a local git repo, then do a merge, and some time later I fetch some new changes, but this time I do rebase instead of merge, then the previously created merge commit disappears. Why?

**Example**

Consider the following starting point, created by the command `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline`:

```
* 28992d3 (repo1/master) hello4
* 3610bdf hello3
| * f113d63 (HEAD -> master) bye-bye
| * cabc896 bye
|/  
* 75f7ca9 hello2
* 525cb4a hello1
```

I.e., there is a git repo, with a `master` branch with some local, unpushed changes. Some other changes have been just fetched from the remote (in this case `repo1`).

Next command: `git merge repo1/master`. Result:

```
*   b94aa29 (HEAD -> master) Merge remote-tracking branch 'repo1/master'
|\  
| * 28992d3 (repo1/master) hello4
| * 3610bdf hello3
* | f113d63 bye-bye
* | cabc896 bye
|/  
* 75f7ca9 hello2
* 525cb4a hello1
```

Now let's say there are some new commits both locally, as well as in the remote `repo1`, and then, again the remote contents are fetched from `repo1`, via `git fetch repo1 master`. The result looks like this:

```
* 2e3d749 (repo1/master) hello6
* b17983d hello5
| * 2e49819 (HEAD -> master) see ya
| * c2f2d5a good-bye
| *   b94aa29 Merge remote-tracking branch 'repo1/master'
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | 28992d3 hello4
* | 3610bdf hello3
| * f113d63 bye-bye
| * cabc896 bye
|/  
* 75f7ca9 hello2
* 525cb4a hello1
```

So far so good.
Now let's do `git rebase repo1/master`, and the result is a nice, linear commit log:

```
* 101e524 (HEAD -> master) see ya
* 3ce7543 good-bye
* 849cbd4 bye-bye
* 483bab8 bye
* 2e3d749 (repo1/master) hello6
* b17983d hello5
* 28992d3 hello4
* 3610bdf hello3
* 75f7ca9 hello2
* 525cb4a hello1
```

**Question: where did the commit `b94aa29 Merge remote-tracking branch 'repo1/master'` go?** (As far as I see it was not preserved even as a "dead" commit, like e.g. doing commits in detached head.)

Remarks:

- I guess that the answer must lie along the lines of "git notices we don't need `b94aa29` anymore, because we will have all its contents anyway", but can you please explain more in detail what is going on? And also, is this always true, that rebasing on a previously merged branch will throw away all merge commits?
- It would be nice to know, if you can somehow force the merge commit to remain.
- If the example can be simplified, I'm willing to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR version of answer

`git rebase` functionally means:

- pick out some set of commits to copy;
- copy those commits, one at a time, as if by `git cherry-pick`;
- when done, change the current branch name, whatever that is, to point to the final copied commit.

The copying literally *can't* copy merges, so it usually doesn't bother trying.

#### Longer (but see other answers of mine for much more)

The general idea here is to take a series of commits:

```
             A--B--C--D   <-- topic (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--*--o--o   <-- mainline
```

and transplant them to a series of new-and-improved commits:

```
             A--B--C--D   [abandoned]
            /
...--o--o--*--o--o   <-- mainline
                  \
                   A'-B'-C'-D'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

The "improvement" is to base the new chain on the tip of some other branch, such as `mainline`.  To make this happen, Git literally *must* copy the original commits—`A-B-C-D`, here—to different commits that have different hash IDs, because every commit, once made, is permanent<sup>1</sup> and set in stone; a commit that is even one single bit different gives you a new, *different* commit hash ID, even if the only difference is the parent ID stored in the new commit.  So even if the source tree in snapshot `A'` matches the source tree in snapshot `A`—and it probably doesn't—the commit ID for `A'` is different from the commit ID for `A`.

(This carries on through the rest of the commits as well, of course.)

The arguments you give to `git rebase` select:

- which commits to copy, and
- where to start the copies (where to put the first-copied commit).

Normally you can get away with a single name for both of these.  For instance, `git rebase mainline` means to put the copies after the commit to which `mainline` points, and to copy those commits that are reachable from the commit to which `topic` (the current branch name) points—i.e., `D`—excluding any commits reachable from the tip of `mainline`.  The first commit that's *not* copied is commit `*`, where the two branches rejoin (in this case forever).

In some cases, you may need to use `git rebase --onto` to separate the two notions.  With `--onto`, you tell rebase *where to put the copies*, freeing up the remaining argument to mean *what not to copy*.  That's not required here.

There are a bunch of kinds/flavors of rebase: `git rebase` with no arguments uses `git format-patch | git am` to copy commits, rather than actually running `git cherry-pick`, while `git rebase -i` actually uses `git cherry-pick`.  (In older versions of Git, `git rebase -i` is a shell script that literally runs `git cherry-pick`.  To make it faster for Windows, `git rebase` was modified so that `-i` is built in to Git's *sequencer*, which is code that implements both cherry-pick and revert.)

Note that all this copying, which goes one at a time, ends up building a *linear chain* of commits.  **This happens even if the inputs might include a merge**, as in:

```
          A--B--M--C--D   <-- master
         /     /
...--o--*--o--S------o--T   <-- repo1/master
```

You now ask Git to rebase (i.e., copy) some commits—in this case, some commits that are on `master`—with the `--onto` target being `T`, and the limit being *the first commit reachable from `T` / `origin/master` that is also on `master`, which is commit `*`.

The complete list of such commits is `A` then `B` then `M` then `C` then `D`.  But how should Git copy `M`?  If it *tried*, the result might look a lot like:

```
          A--B--M--C--D   [abandoned]
         /     /
...--o--*--o--S------o--T   <-- repo1/master
                         \
                          A'-B'-M'-C'-D   <-- master (HEAD)
                               /
                  ???----------
```

except `M'`, to be a merge, needs to have *two* parents.  What other parent should it have?  If its other parent is `S`, well, that's *possible*, but what value does it bring?

(The point of a merge is to combine changes in two different lines of development.  Since `A'` is based on `T` which is based on `S`, `A'` already includes whatever was in `S` and there is no need to merge it.)

In general, Git simply *omits* the merge commits entirely here, so it ends up copying just `A-B-C-D`.  Note that if you rebase something containing an *internal* merge, the same thing happens: Git simply copies both "sides" of the merge, linearizing the result:

```
                 C--D
                /    \
            A--B      M--G   <-- topic (HEAD)
           /    \    /
          /      E--F
         /
...--o--*--o--o   <-- mainline
```

Here `git rebase` will copy `A-B-C-D-E-F-G` or perhaps `A-B-E-F-C-D-G`, removing `M` and flattening the topology.

There is a `-p` flag to `git rebase -i`, which has a longer spelling `--preserve-merges`, but it doesn't actually *preserve* the merges (nor cherry-pick them, which is impossible).  Instead, it *makes new merges* (by running `git merge`).  This is quite tricky, but can be used to rebase the above `A-B-(C-D, E-F)-M-G` topology.  Note that if you resolved merge conflicts in `M`, you will have to resolve them again when Git makes a new merge `M'` that merges `D'` and `F'` (`git rerere` may be useful here).

---

<sup>1</sup>Permanent, that is, until the entire commit has been abandoned long enough for Git to be sure that no one wants it; then it gets cleaned away by `git gc`.